# Python Django multiprocessing Error: "AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Command.handle.<locals>.f'"

Tags: python, django, multiprocessing

I'm using python 3.6 django 1.11 windows10 and trying to send email using multiprocessing.

recipients are connected to database(django model) and email contents form is html(by django get_template), also used get_connection to send multi-email. What I'm trying is to use multiprocessing to accelerate sending rate.

My code is here

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.mail import get_connection, EmailMessage
from django.template.loader import get_template

from multiprocessing import Pool

from sending.models import Subscriber


class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):

        connection = get_connection()

        recipients = [i.email for i in Subscriber.objects.all()]
        num = Subscriber.objects.count()

        subject = 'Multiprocessing trying 1'
        body = get_template('Newsletter20171229.html').render()
        from_email = 'info@modoodoc.com'


        def send(i):
            msg = EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, [recipients[i]])
            msg.content_subtype = 'html'

            print("Sending email to: " + recipients[i] + " No: " + str(i))
            connection.send_messages([msg])
            print("Complete.")

        pool = Pool(processes=2)
        pool.map(send, range(0, num))


        print("Mail have just sent. The program is going to end.")
        connection.close()
```

And I've got an error like this.

```
  File "c:\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "c:\python36-32\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'Command.handle.<locals>.f'
```

How to fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You must take the local function `send` out of `handle` (and the `Command` class) and **put it at the top level of your module**, according to [the reference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled).

For closured variables like `subject`, `body`, `from_email`, etc., you can bundle them in a `tuple` and pass the `tuple` as a single argument to `send`. Or better, create `msg` objects outside `send`, and pass the `msg` list to `pool.map()`:

```
msg_list = [EmailMessage(subject, body, from_email, [recipients[i]])
            for i in range(0, num)]

for msg in msg_list
    msg.content_subtype = 'html'

pool = Pool(processes=2)
pool.map(send, msg_list)
```

in which the **module-level** `send` function is defined as follows:

```
def send(msg):
    print("Sending email to: {}".format(msg.recipients()[0]))
    connection.send_messages([msg])
    print("Complete.")
```